# Using JsonConverter on default value while ignoring default values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I just upgraded my json serializer from newtonsoft 4.5 to 5 -
I have a custom `JsonConverter` to handle `DateTime` types, and it converts my dates to numbers I work with, but having `DafaultValueHandling` set to `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` it doesn't work on `DateTime`'s that are `null`.

I would like my custom `JsonConverter` to convert values of `DateTime` even if they're null, but also use the setting `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`.

Can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record - if someone runs into the same problem - It seems that this just can't be done with newtonsoft json converter.
It turns out that it first ignores the values that are defualt values, and only then uses your `CustomConverter`s for the properties left that have values.

Answer (score -2):

Since the `DateTime's` default value is `null`, your `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` setting ignores it. So here you could set your own default value for `DateTime` property.

By doing this way, the JsonSerializer will assume now that `null` is not the default value of DateTime and so your JsonConvertor will work when it encounter `null` in DateTime. See an example below.

```
public class TempClass
{
    [DefaultValue(DateTime.MinValue)]
    public DateTime CurrentDate;
}
```

In the above example, `DateTime.MinValue` is set as the default value for CurrentDate property. So if the `CurrentDate` is null, then the same is not ignored by `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`.

Haven't tried this but hope it will work.

Comment: DateTime cannot be null, it has an actual default value which is equal to `new DateTime()`. Disregarding that, this still isn't a good solution since i have a really big codebase with many objects like these, I don't want to go over all of them and add that attribute, what more I don't want each time I (or another developer on my team) to add an object have to add this attribute.